# How to update a dataframe from a new dataframe that has an additional column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the help page for [pandas.DataFrame.update](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) they have the following example to update df with new_df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [400, 500, 600]})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [4, 5, 6],
                       'C': [7, 8, 9]})
df.update(new_df)
df
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

What is the best way to get 'C' to show up as a new column in df using the update command? I could not figure it out, but if I create the new column in df using either of the following:

```
df['C'] = np.NaN
df['C'] = 0
```

that seems to populate it, but I'm wondering if there is a better way or some way to do it in the df.update.

Comment: pandas.DataFrame.update  aligns both row and column indexes for update.  So if your base df doesn't have that index (column), it won't update it.   Either you create an empty column like you do now, or you have to do it another way (can't use update)

Comment: You can use df.merge() to make the column 'C' show up

Comment: See my discussion below as an answer.  In summary, although there are some other ways to create columns C in df, the contents of existing columns e.g. column B could be different from the result of column B by calling `.update()` or you have to call it in an counterintuitive way.

Answer (score 4):

`df.update` Aligns on indices. You can use [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to overwrite the previous value and adding new columns too.

```
df.assign(**new_df)

   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Answer (score 4):

There is another way where we could use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) and make sure right DataFrames are passed to it. If you pass it correct manner then you will get expected output.

```
new_df.combine_first(df)
    A   B   C
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is aimed at discussing the differences of [`DataFrame.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with various similar functions, such as [`.combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) and [`.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) discussed in this post.

An example is sometimes better than thousand words.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [400, 500, np.nan]})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [4, np.nan, 6],
                       'C': [7, 8, 9]})

df
   A      B
0  1  400.0
1  2  500.0
2  3    NaN

new_df
     B  C
0  4.0  7
1  NaN  8
2  6.0  9
```

#### Using [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df.update(new_df)
   A      B
0  1    4.0
1  2  500.0              <==  500 from column B of df is NOT replaced by NaN from new_df
2  3    6.0
```

Note also that `df` after the update (in place) still **contains 2 columns only**.

#### Using [`.combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

```
df.combine_first(new_df)
   A      B  C
0  1  400.0  7
1  2  500.0  8
2  3    6.0  9           <==  Only NaN entry in column B of df got replaced
```

Note that we have 3 columns in the result here.

Next, let's try reversing the subject and object of the call:

```
new_df.combine_first(df)
   A      B  C
0  1    4.0  7
1  2  500.0  8           <==  Only NaN entry in column B of new_df got replaced
2  3    6.0  9
```

Note that we have 3 columns in the result here.  Different from the result of [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

This is among all the nearest to the result of [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) but still with one column more. Moreover, we have to reverse the subject and object in the call: we want to update `df` but have to call using `new_df` to get similar result.  This is not so intuitive.

#### Using [`.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

```
df.assign(**new_df)
   A    B  C
0  1  4.0  7
1  2  NaN  8             <==  500 from column B of df got replaced by NaN from new_df
2  3  6.0  9
```

Note that we have 3 columns in the result here.  Different from the result of [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

#### How to get column `C` to show up as a new column in `df` using [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) command?

Since only values at matching index/column labels are updated, we can achieve this by using [`.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) on the union of both row and column indexes before using [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) command, as follows:

```
df = df.reindex(index=df.index.union(new_df.index), 
                columns=df.columns.union(new_df.columns))
df.update(new_df)
   A      B    C
0  1    4.0  7.0
1  2  500.0  8.0
2  3    6.0  9.0
```

This works better than manually creating missing columns and rows in `df` for there could be multiple row and column indexes to add for large datasets.